# django import some fields by excel and some fields by default

Tags: python, django, excel

My view code for importing data in the db is like this :

```
def excel_import(request):
    uploadform=UploadFileForm(None)
    if request.method == 'POST' :
        uploadform = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if uploadform.is_valid():
            file = uploadform.cleaned_data['docfile']
            data = bytes()
            for chunk in file.chunks():
                data += chunk
            dataset = XLS().create_dataset(data)
            result = ExportSpec().import_data(dataset,dry_run=False, 
                                              raise_errors=True, 
                                              user=request.user)

    return render(request, 'BallbearingSite/news.html',
                  {'uploadform':uploadform})
```

and my models is like this :

```
class Stocks(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(blank=True,null=True,upload_to='documents/')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128,verbose_name=_('stockname'))
    number = models.CharField(max_length=64,verbose_name=_('number'))
    suffix = models.CharField(max_length=12,verbose_name=_('uffix'))
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=64, validators=[
                          RegexValidator(regex='^[A-Z]*$', message=_(u'brand must be in Capital letter'),)], verbose_name=_('brand'))
    comment = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, 
                             max_length=264, verbose_name=_('comment'))
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True,  
                                      verbose_name=_('price'))
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True,verbose_name=_('date'))

    checking = ((_('pending'),_('pending')),
                (_('reject'),_('reject')),
                (_('approved'),_('approved')),
                (_('expired'),_('expired')),
               )
    confirm = models.CharField(choices=checking,max_length=10, 
                             verbose_name=_('confirmation'), 
                             default=_('pending'))
    seller = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('seller'))
```

I want to get some fields by excel file and some fields like date,confirm,user set by default
also the id  should set by default as latest id+1 for each row of the excel file

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/) when working with Excel files and [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) to insert into database with 1 query. Below is a code example.

```
import openpyxl, datetime

file = uploadform.cleaned_data['docfile']
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file, read_only=True)
# Get name of the first sheet and then open sheet by name
first_sheet = workbook.get_sheet_names()[0]
worksheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(first_sheet)

data = []

for row in worksheet.iter_rows(row_offset=1): # Offset for header
    stock = Stocks()
    stock.user = request.user
    stock.name = row[0].value
    stock.number = row[1].value
    stock.suffix = row[2].value
    stock.brand = row[3].value
    stock.comment = row[4].value
    stock.price = row[5].value
    stock.date = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    stock.confirm = 'approved'
    stock.seller = row[6].value
    data.append(stock)

# Bulk create data
Stocks.objects.bulk_create(data)
```

[bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) has some caveats so do read documentation before using it.

Comment: Probably because you have an empty row in your file. I wrote a sample code. You cannot expect perfectly working code for your particular case. Adjust it to your requirement.

Comment: What about saving data from a form? I add this part of code but doesnt work :    [ #in the for loop:]
            stock.seller = uploadform.cleaned_data.get("seller") 
[after Stocks.objects.bulk_create(data):]
             instance=uploadform.save()
              instance.user=request.user
              instance.save() @Borut

Comment: With `bulk_create` you are by-passing the usual `save()` method and you directly create objects in the database. You'd add seller in the loop as you said with `stock.seller = uploadform.cleaned_data.get('seller')` and current user with `stock.user = request.user`.

Comment: but it doesnt save the seller and the seller field is always checked in admin page! The form which contains seller is : 
 `class UploadFileForm(forms.Form): docfile = forms.FileField(label=_("Enter an Excel file")) CHOICES=[('0','buyer'), ('1',' seller')] seller = forms.ChoiceField(label=_(''),choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect()) `
 
and the Model is what i wrote above. Is there anything wrong with these codes ?
@Borut

Comment: I changed the view to :
`CHOICES=[(False,'buyer'), (True,' seller')] seller = forms.ChoiceField(label=_(''),choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect())`
still no changes
@Borut

Comment: I got it :
`bool('True') and bool('False') always return True because strings 'True' and 'False' are not empty.`
so i changed the code to :
`stock.seller = eval(uploadform.cleaned_data.get("seller"))`
and its working now . Thank you Borut

Comment: It's not really safe to use `eval()` in this situation, because somebody could change your string to some bad code, post it and `eval()` would execute it. Rather use a one-liner like `True if uploadform.cleaned_data.get('seller') == 'True' else False`.